# React MUI - Operating on dynamically created TextField elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to dynamically add pairs of buttons and text fields and have the button perform some action on its corresponding text field. My specific use case is creating a 'User Settings' page where users can change a specific account information property

Here is a minimal code example that generates 2 pairs of text fields and buttons. However, pressing either button disables both text fields rather than its corresponding text field:

```js
export default function FAQ() {

    const [disabled, toggleDisabled] = React.useState(false)

    const CreateInputPair = () => {
        return (
            <>
                <TextField
                    disabled={disabled}
                />
                <Button
                    onClick={() => toggleDisabled(!disabled)}
                >
                    Toggle Disabled
                </Button>
            </>
        )
    }

    return (
        <>
            <CreateInputPair />
            <br />
            <CreateInputPair />
        </>
    );

}
```

In the above example, how can I make it so that pressing a button only disables its associated text field?

My current and naive approach for reading values of dynamically created elements is to assign `id` prop fields to the TextField and manipulate the DOM to read the value (ie. having `document.getElementById(e.target.id).value` inside a `onClick={(e) => handleChange(e)}` method), but this goes against the principles of React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `CreateInputPair` into its own separate component.

```
const InputPair = () => {
    const [disabled, toggleDisabled] = React.useState(false);
    return (
        <>
            <TextField
                disabled={disabled}
            />
            <Button
                onClick={() => toggleDisabled(!disabled)}
            >
                Toggle Disabled
            </Button>
        </>
    )
}
export default function FAQ() {
    return <>
        <InputPair /> <br /> <InputPair />
    </>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function FAQ() {
  const [disabled, toggleDisabled] = useState();

  const toggleDisabledInput = (id) => {
    if (disabled === id) {
      toggleDisabled(null);
    } else {
      toggleDisabled(id);
    }
  };

  console.log(disabled);

  const CreateInputPair = ({ id }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <input disabled={disabled === id} />
        <button onClick={() => toggleDisabledInput(id)}>Toggle Disabled</button>
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <CreateInputPair id="1" /> // you can pass id from your db
      <br />
      <CreateInputPair id="2" />
    </>
 );
}
```